# How to make a simple proxy in python?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I wanted to make a very simple proxy using python (mostly to understand how it works). I am talking about a generic TCP proxy, not only http.
I have built the following code, however, it seems to only work one way : ie the request is sent but I never get the answer. Here is the code :

```
import socket
import argparse

#Args
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='ProxyDescription')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--listen', action='store', help='Listening port', default=80, type=int)
parser.add_argument('destination', action='store', help='Destination host')
parser.add_argument('port', action='store', help='Destination port', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

#Server
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.bind(('', args.listen))
s1.listen(1)
conn1, addr1 = s1.accept()

#Client
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.connect((args.destination, args.port))
s2.setblocking(0)

print "Connected by ", addr1
while 1:
    datato = conn1.recv(1024)
    if not datato: 
        print "breaking to"
        break
    s2.send(datato)
    print "data send : " + datato
    try:
        datafrom = s2.recv(1024)
        print "reveived data : " + datafrom   
        if not datafrom:
            print "breakinf from"
            break
        print "datafrom: " + datafrom
        conn1.send(datafrom)
    except socket.error, msg:
        print "error rcving: " + str(socket.error) + " || " + str(msg) 
        continue
print "the end ... closing"
conn1.close()
s2.close()
```

My test is simply launching this script and telnet through it. If I look with wireshark, I see that the request is fully understood by the server and I do get an answer, however, I never get the answer in the telnet. (testing with simple GET / on google)
I feel the problem is related to "blocking" / "non-blocking" socket but I can't really understand where it is.

Comment: how much data did the `conn1.send()` indicate has been sent?

Comment: it actually never gets there since s2.recv(1024) doesn't receive anything :/

Comment: oh. then it's simple - since s2 is non blocking, recv will return immediately, and your code will break the loop. make it non blocking and see! but this will not work well in the real world, the real way to do it is either using a non blocking networking API, or using 2 threads.